# IE7 & 8: .is(':checked') is ignored when hiding input buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form: http://jsfiddle.net/q2BnA/1/ . I want to be able to click on Option 1, and give focus to field1, click on Option 2, and give focus to field2. So, I have JQuery to do that. It works good, until I add this style:

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]  {
        display:none;
    }
```

Now I have a problem in IE8 and IE7 (I have to support them) - focus is not given. I am assuming it's because of this line: *var option1 = $('#option1').is('**:checked**')*;

But I have to hide radio buttons because I am styling my own via:

```
input[type=radio] + label {
    /*look nice*/
}
```

How can I resolve this for IEs?

**JQ**

```
function focusThis() {
        var option1 = $('#option1').is(':checked');
        if (option1) {
            //alert(1);
            $('#field1').focus();
        } else {
            //alert(2);
            $('#field2').focus();
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
<fieldset><legend>Options</legend>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="A" id="option1" onclick="focusThis();"><label for="option1">Option 1</label> 
            <label for="field1">Field 1</label><input id="field1"/></li>

        <li><input type="radio" name="A" id="option2" onclick="focusThis();"><label for="option2">Option 2</label>

            <fieldset id=""><legend></legend>
              <ul>
                <li><label for="field2">Field 2</label> <input id="field2"/></li>
                  <li><label for="field3">Field 3</label> <input id="field3"/></li>
              </ul>
          </fieldset>
         </li>
      </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Which version of jquery?

Comment: Our site is currently linking to jquery-1.8.2, but I can change that if other versions resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `display: none` is slightly more than cosmetic, so you have to sidestep it.

How about putting the inputs inside the labels, hiding them with `opacity: 0` (and the IE equivalent) instead, and making them occupy the full dimensions of their containers?

The new code is as follows:

```
<label for="option1">
    <input type="radio" name="A" id="option1" onclick="focusThis();">
    Option 1
</label>
```

…and for the CSS:

```
label {
    position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]  {
    opacity: 0;
    /* IE 5-7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Forked your demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/barney/M8nnb/1

Comment: What would be the advantage of that vs shooting off the radio button display via `position:absolute; left:-9999px`?

Comment: Good question. 1) The negative box model indent results in calculating a huge extra piece of layout, [which has been known to negatively impact performance in some cases](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/). 2) This behaviour effectively has the user interacting with the inputs directly (rather than implicitly, via their associated labels): [this can be more reliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747945/how-to-get-firefox-click-behaviour-to-work-properly-with-css-styled-checkbox-an).

Comment: @Barney your first link refers to text-indent which effectively could generate some performance issue. I could be wrong but i don't see how it could be related to the current case using position absolute. I don't really know how to do some benchmarks on it though.

Comment: @roasted you're right, it's more fear than fact — and yes, there's a distinct difference between simply positioning something thousands of pixels off page and forcing the box model to occupy all those pixels. For a generic invisibility solution, I'd go for the HTML5 boilerplate [`.visuallyhidden`](https://gist.github.com/sousk/1280108)

Comment: @Barney This `.visuallyhidden` looks good. I'm thinking to use it for my future projects now that weighs on me some fear...   ;)

Comment: I was trying out both solutions. Using `left:-9999px; top:-9999px;` causes weird behavior in Firefox: when an input is selected, FF jumps to the top of the page. My form is long, so it's really annoying to be at the bottom checking options, and being bumped up to the top every button click I make. I think it's because it's jumping to original button, which is at -9999px (top in this case). If I set it to +9999px, it jumps to that side of the screen on every click! Not good.

Answer (score 1):

Then don't use `display none`, use this workaround:

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]  {
       position:absolute;
       left:-9999px;
       top:-9999px;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLSW8/)

Answer (score 0):

The focus on the **current** control is required for the click event.

Look at this thread: [Changing Javascript Focus in onClick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896521/changing-javascript-focus-in-onclick-event).

I'll suggest to use event.PreventDefault(); look at this answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/335905